# How to add :nth-child() with list when three alternative colors repeat to the list?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give the alternative colors to the first three list and I need to repeat these 3 colors to next 3 list onwards, but unfortunately I didn't get it work as per my requirement. Please help me!

```css
ul li:nth-child(1n + 0) {
  background: #1A1A1A;
}

ul li:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #F7882F;
}

ul li:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  background: #F7C331;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did it the wrong way around.

The “formula” is explained here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#Functional_notation

You want to select any 3rd element, and add different offsets to that.

```
ul li:nth-child(3n + 0) {
  background: #1A1A1A;
}
ul li:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  background: #F7882F;
}
ul li:nth-child(3n + 2) {
  background: #F7C331;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You was not to wrong.
Good example for this is: https://themarklee.com/2013/09/29/repeating-patterns-nth-child/

```css
ul li:nth-child(3n + 1) {
background: #1A1A1A;
}
ul li:nth-child(3n + 2) {
background: #F7882F;
}
ul li:nth-child(3n + 3) {
background: #F7C331;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>List</li>
<li>List</li>
<li>List</li>
<li>List</li>
<li>List</li>
<li>List</li>
<li>List</li>
<li>List</li>
<li>List</li>
</ul>
```